# PHP. How to get a list of week days of selected month?

Tags: php, arrays, list, date, datetime

I have code which returns number of business days in selected month/years. I need to get a list of week days to control It, for example:

```
if (friday) {
$i = 1;
}

if (thursday) {
$i = 0;
}
```

And code which I use for calculating weekdays:

```
<?php
//The function returns the no. of business days between two dates and it skips the holidays
function getWorkingDays($startDate,$endDate,$holidays){
    // do strtotime calculations just once
    $endDate = strtotime($endDate);
    $startDate = strtotime($startDate);


    //The total number of days between the two dates. We compute the no. of seconds and divide it to 60*60*24
    //We add one to inlude both dates in the interval.
    $days = ($endDate - $startDate) / 86400 + 1;

    $no_full_weeks = floor($days / 7);
    $no_remaining_days = fmod($days, 7);

    //It will return 1 if it's Monday,.. ,7 for Sunday
    $the_first_day_of_week = date("N", $startDate);
    $the_last_day_of_week = date("N", $endDate);

    //---->The two can be equal in leap years when february has 29 days, the equal sign is added here
    //In the first case the whole interval is within a week, in the second case the interval falls in two weeks.
    if ($the_first_day_of_week <= $the_last_day_of_week) {
        if ($the_first_day_of_week <= 6 && 6 <= $the_last_day_of_week) $no_remaining_days--;
        if ($the_first_day_of_week <= 7 && 7 <= $the_last_day_of_week) $no_remaining_days--;
    }
    else {
        // (edit by Tokes to fix an edge case where the start day was a Sunday
        // and the end day was NOT a Saturday)

        // the day of the week for start is later than the day of the week for end
        if ($the_first_day_of_week == 7) {
            // if the start date is a Sunday, then we definitely subtract 1 day
            $no_remaining_days--;

            if ($the_last_day_of_week == 6) {
                // if the end date is a Saturday, then we subtract another day
                $no_remaining_days--;
            }
        }
        else {
            // the start date was a Saturday (or earlier), and the end date was (Mon..Fri)
            // so we skip an entire weekend and subtract 2 days
            $no_remaining_days -= 2;
        }
    }

    //The no. of business days is: (number of weeks between the two dates) * (5 working days) + the remainder
//---->february in none leap years gave a remainder of 0 but still calculated weekends between first and last day, this is one way to fix it
   $workingDays = $no_full_weeks * 5;
    if ($no_remaining_days > 0 )
    {
      $workingDays += $no_remaining_days;
    }

    //We subtract the holidays
    foreach($holidays as $holiday){
        $time_stamp=strtotime($holiday);
        //If the holiday doesn't fall in weekend
        if ($startDate <= $time_stamp && $time_stamp <= $endDate && date("N",$time_stamp) != 6 && date("N",$time_stamp) != 7)
            $workingDays--;
    }

    return $workingDays;
}

//Example:

$holidays=array("2008-12-25","2008-12-26","2009-01-01");

echo getWorkingDays("2008-12-22","2009-01-02",$holidays)
// => will return 7
?>
```

Is It possible to make It? Thank you for answers.

Comment: What is your **actual problem**? Can you `var_dump()` what you have as **result**, and what you **expect**?

Comment: Thank you for answers. I'm writing a program where I need to make some thing every Friday, Saturday etc. So for example I need to make that every Friday $i variable will be increased by 1.

Comment: try my edited answer, it might help you

Comment: Attention: you must NOT assume that all days are 86,400 seconds long. That can lead to unexpected results!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below:

```
$startDate = new DateTime( '2013-04-01' );    //intialize start date
$endDate = new DateTime( '2013-04-30' );    //initialize end date
$holiday = array('2013-04-11','2013-04-25');  //this is assumed list of holiday
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');    // set the interval as 1 day
$daterange = new DatePeriod($startDate, $interval ,$endDate);
$i = 0;
foreach($daterange as $date){
if($date->format("N") == 5)   // OR if($date->format("l") == "Friday") 
  $i++;
}
echo $i;
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, It returning list of days in month, but I need a list with names of week days, I mean It should return that 25 of September is Thursday. I'm writing a program where I need to make some thing every Friday, Saturday etc.

Comment: @Infinity: you can change "$date->format("Y-m-d");" format to $date->format("d l"); // lowercase L will show you day as Friday, Saturday etc..

Comment: Thank you for answer, but how It works? If for example I set startDate and endDate to 2014-10-03 It should return that It Friday, but It return 0.

Comment: code will give you the total count of friday in an interval.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it increase $i on every occurrence of Friday between two dates

```
$startdate ="2008-12-22";
$enddate="2009-01-22";

$i=0;
while($startdate <= $enddate)
{

$startdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($startdate)));

$day = date("d",strtotime($startdate));
$month = date("m",strtotime($startdate));
$year = date("Y",strtotime($startdate));

if(date("l", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year)) == "Friday" )
{
       echo $day."-".$month."-".$year." is ".date("l", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year))."\n" ;
       $i++; \\ increase $i on every occurrence of Friday
}

}
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cf698f9a4a0e4d23374c54b3d8fd5d18eed4482e)